# Why does make run one specific rule 3 times in a loop?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, transformation

I wrote a makefile that takes a Word DOCX file and (with the help of tei-xslt, xslt scripts and saxon) generates a representation in TEI-XML, HTML files, and a zip file for the ingest into a publication software. The different steps should go like this:

```
DOCX -> TEI-XML -> HTML -> (manifest.yml) -> ZIP # (Expected)
```

The problem is that make runs the TEI to HTML rule three times in a loop before getting to the HTML to ZIP rule:

```
DOCX -> TEI-XML -> -> -> HTML -> (manifest.yml) -> ZIP # (What happens)
                   3x
```

More surprisingly this only happens when the build process had already run at least once before and all the other files already exist in some earlier state. If the folder only contains the DOCX file everything works as expected. Furthermore, there is no difference in using `make all` or just `make`. Make always runs the whole build process, even if no file has changed.

The make file is the following:

```sh
SELF_DIR := $(dir $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))
include ${SELF_DIR}config.mk

MANUSCRIPTFILE:=$(shell ls *.docx)
MANUSCRIPTNAME:=$(shell basename ${MANUSCRIPTFILE} .docx)
SERIES:=$(shell echo "${MANUSCRIPTNAME}" | cut -d _ -f 1)

.PHONY : all tei clean

all: manifold/${MANUSCRIPTNAME}.zip

tei: tei/${MANUSCRIPTNAME}.xml

tei/${MANUSCRIPTNAME}.xml: ${MANUSCRIPTNAME}.docx
    @echo -e "\n[BUILD] Convert Word DOCX to TEI-XML via docxtotei and melusina scripts\n"
# Make available relevant XSL stylesheets to the master styleshet
    @mkdir -p ${TRANSFORMDIR}/melusina/docx/current
# BUG hier findet er das vorhandene Dokument nicht
    @cp ${TRANSFORMDIR}/melusina/docx/specific/${SERIES}.xsl ${TRANSFORMDIR}/melusina/docx/current/series.xsl
    @if [ -e ${TRANSFORMDIR}/melusina/docx/specific/${SERIES}/${MANUSCRIPTNAME}.xsl ]; then\
        cp ${TRANSFORMDIR}/melusina/docx/specific/${SERIES}/${MANUSCRIPTNAME}.xsl ${TRANSFORMDIR}/melusina/docx/current/publication.xsl;\
    else\
        cp ${TRANSFORMDIR}/melusina/empty.xsl ${TRANSFORMDIR}/melusina/docx/current/publication.xsl;\
    fi
    @mkdir -p tei/media
    @${BINDIR}/docxtotei --profiledir=${PROFDIR} --profile=melusina $< $@
    @cp ../../assets/*.png tei/media/
    @cp -r assets/* tei/media/
    @rm -rf ${TRANSFORMDIR}/melusina/docx/current

xhtml/*.html: tei/${MANUSCRIPTNAME}.xml
    @echo -e "\n[BUILD] Convert Word TEI-XML to HTML via teitohtml and melusina scripts\n"
# Make available relevant XSL stylesheets to the master styleshet
    @mkdir -p ${TRANSFORMDIR}/melusina/html/current
    @cp ${TRANSFORMDIR}/melusina/html/specific/${SERIES}.xsl ${TRANSFORMDIR}/melusina/html/current/series.xsl
    @if [ -e ${TRANSFORMDIR}/melusina/html/specific/${SERIES}/${MANUSCRIPTNAME}.xsl ]; then\
        cp ${TRANSFORMDIR}/melusina/html/specific/${SERIES}/${MANUSCRIPTNAME}.xsl ${TRANSFORMDIR}/melusina/html/current/publication.xsl;\
    else\
        cp ${TRANSFORMDIR}/melusina/empty.xsl ${TRANSFORMDIR}/melusina/html/current/publication.xsl;\
    fi
    @mkdir -p xhtml
# generate front matter
    @java -jar ${SAXON}/saxon9he.jar -o:xhtml/front.html $< ${TRANSFORMDIR}/other/html_front_matter.xsl series=${SERIES}
# copy assets from tei folder
    @if [ -e tei/media ]; then\
        cp -r tei/media xhtml/;\
    else\
        mkdir -p xhtml/media;\
    fi
# copy stylesheets
    @cp ${TRANSFORMDIR}/css/melusina.css xhtml/
    @cp ${TRANSFORMDIR}/css/specific/${SERIES}.css xhtml/publication.css
# transform tei xml to html
    @${BINDIR}/teitohtml --profiledir=${PROFDIR} --profile=melusina $< xhtml/${MANUSCRIPTNAME}.html
    @rm -rf ${TRANSFORMDIR}/melusina/html/current

manifold/manifest.yml: tei/${MANUSCRIPTNAME}.xml
    @echo -e "\n[BUILD] Generate manifest.yml from TEI-XML via Saxon and melusina scripts\n"
    @mkdir -p manifold
    @java -jar ${SAXON}/saxon9he.jar -o:manifold/manifest.yml $< ${TRANSFORMDIR}/other/manifold_manifest.xsl

manifold/${MANUSCRIPTNAME}.zip: xhtml/*.html manifold/manifest.yml
    @echo -e "\n[BUILD] Generate Manifold package by collecting manifest.yml and HTML files\n"
    @if [ -e tei/media ]; then\
        cp -r tei/media manifold/;\
    else\
        mkdir -p manifold/media;\
    fi
    @cd xhtml && cp -r cover.html second_cover.html editorial.html *.css ../manifold/
# generate chapter html
    @java -jar ${SAXON}/saxon9he.jar -o:xhtml/sections.html xhtml/${MANUSCRIPTNAME}.html ${TRANSFORMDIR}/other/split_html_sections.xsl
    @cd manifold && zip -r ${MANUSCRIPTNAME}.zip manifest.yml media *.html *.css
# rm -rf manifold/media manifold/${MANUSCRIPTNAME}.html manifest.yml

clean:
    @echo "[BUILD] Delete everything but the Word DOCX manuscript"
    @rm -rf tei xhtml manifold pdf
```

Comment: I'm sure you're familiar with the idea of [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com//help/mcve). It would be very helpful if you pared this makefile somewhat.

Comment: ...Have you checked, have you *actually checked,* what `MANUSCRIPTNAME` contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that these rules cannot work:

```
xhtml/*.html: tei/${MANUSCRIPTNAME}.xml

manifold/${MANUSCRIPTNAME}.zip: xhtml/*.html manifold/manifest.yml
```

It cannot be correct to use wildcards to find *target* that need to be built by make, because when you run make the first time no files exist that match those wildcards so they cannot expand.

The reason it appears to work is that, just like the shell, if a wildcard doesn't match any value it returns the wildcard itself.  So, if no files match `xhtml/*.html` then the result is the literal string `xhtml/*.html`.  If you have three files that match, then the result is the three files like `xhtml/ONE.html xhtml/TWO.html xhtml/THREE.html`.

So the first time you run this makefile there are no targets that match and so make wants to build one target named, literally, `xhtml/*.html` and there is a rule that matches that target, so it all works.

The second time you run this makefile there are three targets make wants to build and there is a rule like this:

```
xhtml/ONE.html xhtml/TWO.html xhtml/THREE.html: tei/${MANUSCRIPTNAME}.xml
        ...recipe...
```

What does this mean?  You may think it means one invocation of *recipe* will build all three targets, but that's not what it means to make.  To make, this is exactly the same as writing this:

```
xhtml/ONE.html: tei/${MANUSCRIPTNAME}.xml
        ...recipe...
xhtml/TWO.html: tei/${MANUSCRIPTNAME}.xml
        ...recipe...
xhtml/THREE.html: tei/${MANUSCRIPTNAME}.xml
        ...recipe...
```

that is, it will run *recipe* one time for each target.  It's impossible for me to understand what that mass of shell scripting does so I can't say why it's always rebuilding: it must be that either those files are not actually created by the target, or their modification times are not set properly.

If this rule really builds all the html files with one invocation, then you need to use a pseudo-target of some kind to track its modification time, like this:

```
xhtml/.buildhtml: tei/${MANUSCRIPTNAME}.xml
        ... recipe ...
        @touch $@

manifold/${MANUSCRIPTNAME}.zip: xhtml/.buildhtml manifold/manifest.yml
```

Alternatively if you know you can rely on having the latest GNU make 4.3 version, you can take advantage of the new ["grouped targets" feature](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multiple-Targets.html), `&:`, and write your makefile like this:

```
ALLHTML = xhtml/ONE.html xhtml/TWO.html xhtml/THREE.html
$(ALLHTML) &: tei/${MANUSCRIPTNAME}.xml
        ...recipe...

manifold/${MANUSCRIPTNAME}.zip: $(ALLHTML) manifold/manifest.yml
```

(You still cannot use `*.html` for the reasons given above).

Comment: It was the the *.xhtml rule and my misunderstanding of the logic behind it that caused the repitition. The problem of the entire build process running everytime, however, remains both with the dummy and grouped targets solution. Indeed some files are not actually created by the rules but copied from another location. However, I thought make looks at the mtime of a file in order to calculate what needs to be rebuild. The mtime of the copied file is definitely the time of the copy process and looking at the output via `ls -lD` the manuscript *.docx file definitely remains older than the rest.

Comment: It's not really possible for us to debug this here, given the complexity of the scripting you have.  I recommend you use `make -d` and investigate the output to determine why make decides to rebuild targets in ways you don't expect.  If you have questions about why decisions are made you can ask another question on SO (you won't be able to paste the entire output so you'll have to show only the relevant parts or else create a sample makefile that reproduces the behavior using `touch` etc. rather than all the tools you have)